# Is there a way to restore images to S3 when they were not uploaded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In a Django app I'm using storages and images were uploaded to an S3 bucket.
At some point `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'` this part was deleted from the settings and all that time images were not uploaded to the bucket. Now is there a way to somehow restore these images if I have the image path saved in the db like this?
[https://my-cloudfront-id.cloudfront.net/media/profile_pictures/kupp.jpg"](https://my-cloudfront-id.cloudfront.net/media/profile_pictures/kupp.jpg%22)

Comment: Where does the Django app run?

Comment: On an Elastic Beanstalk python platform

Comment: Then probably you have some sort of block storage attached to your EC2 instance? I’d try logging in on the instance and see if you can find something there.

Comment: If that doesn’t help you might have to add much more detail to your questions to give us an understanding of your context.

Comment: You mean EFS or Instance Store?

Comment: I would check both, depending on how your application is configured.

Comment: I don't have attached storage systems.